# Subversion tagging subset of files

Tags: svn

With Subversion, is there a simple way to tag only a subset of the files in trunk?

I would like to make multiple tags of the trunk. One tag which contains all the files in trunk, and a few tags with selected subset of the files. The contents of the subset tags are to be delivered to different customers with different needs. Most of the files will go into all of the tags, but all.

It could look like this:

```
tags/v1.0.0         (contains everything from trunk)
tags/v1.0.0_xxx     (subset xxx from trunk)
tags/v1.0.0_yyy
tags/v1.0.0_zzz
```

It would of course be possible to write a script that reads file lists for each tag variant, and copies the files one by one from trunk to the correct tags folder in the repo. But that's a lot of work, and will result in thousands of svn revision numbers. If it could be done in one action, so the svn revision number only increments a little, it would be nice.

Does anyone know a simple way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: You can `svn cp` multiple files at once: `svn cp fileA fileB fileC fileD tags/v1.0.0_xxx`. I hope understand your problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make Subversion tag that is highly customized is to make use of the Subversion client's so-called "WC-to-REPO" copy mechanism -- that is, an `svn copy` operation (or it's GUI equivalent) whose "source" is your working copy and whose "target" is a URL in the repository.

Say you want to make a tag that look exactly like your current `trunk/`, but which has some files removed or modified.  First, get a local working copy of that `trunk/` at the HEAD revision (via `svn checkout` or `svn update`).  Now, modify the working copy until it looks exactly like what you wish to tag.  Be sure to use Subversion operations for anything that adds or removes files and directories (`svn mkdir`, `svn add`, `svn rm`, ...).

Now, **do not commit your changes**.  Rather, use `svn copy` to copy your working copy to a new tag URL.

```
$ svn copy . http://svn.myserver.com/repo/tags/my-new-branch -m "Make a custom tag"
```

The Subversion client will efficiently construct at the tag location in the repository a replica of what it finds in your working copy.

Many projects (like the Subversion and ViewVC projects) use exactly this approach in order to create release tags from release branches.  Generally, there is some source code file that carries the software's version string, and you don't want un-released code to carry a version string that would indicate that the code is, in fact, already released.  So in a release branch (`branches/1.2.x/`, say) that source code file might have something like this:

```
__version__ = "1.2.4-dev"
```

Once that release branch has been tested and blessed as ready for release, the project *could* just tag the branch and then come along in a subsequent commit to fix the `__version__` string by removing the "-dev" bit.

```
$ svn checkout .../branches/1.2.x my-working-copy
$ cd my-working-copy
$ # test, test, and test some more
$ svn copy ^/branches/1.2.x ^/tags/1.2.4 -m "Tag the 1.2.4 release (almost)"
$ svn switch ^/tags/1.2.4 # make the working copy temporarily point to the new tag
$ vi ./lib/version.py # change the __version__ string to drop the "-dev"
$ svn commit -m "Just kidding.  Now it's *really* 1.2.4."
$ svn switch ^/branches/1.2.x # make the working point back to the release branch
```

But that means that there's a window of time in which the tag doesn't have exactly the information you want it to.

Using a WC-to-REPO copy is way, way, easier and doesn't have the race condition.

```
$ svn checkout .../branches/1.2.x my-working-copy
$ cd my-working-copy
$ vi ./lib/version.py # change the __version__ string to drop the "-dev"
$ # test, test, and test some more
$ svn cp . ^/tags/1.2.4 -m "Tag the 1.2.4 release."
```

At this point, you can do one of two things.  You can revert the (still-uncommitted) local modifications to the release branch:

```
$ svn revert -R . # undo the local release branch mods
```

Or, you can make *and* commit further local modifications to prepare the branch for the following future release:

```
$ vi ./lib/version.py # change the __version__ string now to "1.2.5-dev"
$ svn commit -m "Begin a new release cycle."
```